# How to query new/changed elements through Overpass API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to perform search by tag using the request like this:

http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=[out:json];node[%22addr:postcode%22=20156];out;

Is it possible to query only for nodes that has been added/modified after some arbitrary date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are the two keywords [`changed`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_date_of_change_.28changed.29) and [`newer`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#newer). Better use `newer` since `changed` requires lots of memory to run, see [issue 278](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/278).

Comment: But changed apparently uses mega amounts of memory, so newer may be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Please put your experiences in a separate answer. To me this sounds more like a bug with a specific version of Overpass API and not like a general advice. It has already been reported at https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/278